# Drupal site. How do I add custom js/css prettify.js/prettify.css for a drupal page?

Tags: html, css, drupal

I want to use custom css/js.  I have moved these to the server.  But the drupal page starts with a  section.  how do I add the custom css/js to my drupal site page.  I have admin and just need to know what to do to get this included on the page.  Please send exact steps as I am totally new to drupal. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

"[Custom CSS and JavaScript files](http://drupal.org/project/customcssjs)" module allows to specify two folders, one for CSS and one for JS where the stylesheets and javascripts files are located respectively.
The module creates two sub-folders under your files folder:
files/customcssjs/css
files/customcssjs/js

**Indeed, it's depend on your task, what css and js files should do, and adding these in [custom module](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) ([drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7), [drupal_add_css](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7)) or custom theme ([info](http://drupal.org/node/171205) file, [preprocess](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) in template.php or directly in [page-XXX.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--page.tpl.php/7) and [so on](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme)).**

Comment: ok.  well here is the situation.  I have one drupal page where I am writing an example that shows some code.  So right now I want to apply it to just that one page for now, but have it available in other pages later.

Comment: I guess I am wondering how to include the js and css so I can reference it inside the body of the pre statement.

Comment: <link href="prettify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="prettify.js"></script>

Comment: since there is no effect unless class='prettyprint" is set I guess i would not mind having this available to any page that wants to use it.

Comment: Ok. How do I add this module to my drupal site?  I have downloaded the zip.

Comment: Ok. I see how to add it but I've got drupal 7.0 and it says this is not compatibile

Comment: You don't tag your question with version. Please try add files from provided links in bold text...